# OpenLDAP recover data without config file

Tags: openldap

We are using OpenLDAP as an LDAP server to test our software with LDAP search support.

Due to an accident our slapd.conf file was deleted.  The person who configured the LDAP server left the company.  Is there a way I can find out how the server was configured and rebuild the config file?

Comment: Restore the configuration from your configuration control or a backup.

Comment: if that would be possible, i wouldn't ask serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect (and change) `slapd`'s config by querying `cn=config` (and its subtree), provided you have the manager password for this realm:

```
ldapsearch -b "cn=config" -D "cn=config" -x -W
[...]
# {2}bdb, config
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcBdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}bdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=openldap
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=employeeType        by dn="cn=user,ou=users,dc=openldap"
[...]
```

I haven't used older `slapd` versions, I entered this when using `slapd.conf` was considered deprecated. So consider the version details below, your milage may vary.

```
# slapd -V
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.23 (Apr 22 2013 05:03:41) $
```

In this version, `slapd`'s config resides in the filesystem in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/` as well in LDIF format.

Comment: I don't have the manager password, so this is not possible either. I ended up creating a new configuration even if it meant losing the old data.